# pandas query with list variables

Tags: mysql, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I made a list of id's each value is is an type int

```
temp_id = [7922, 7018, 5650, 209, 21928, 2294, 10507, 3623]

type(tempasn) 
list
```

---

This works:

```
Temp = pd.read_sql("select count(*) as count\
                    from "+db+"\
                    where ids in (7922, 7018, 5650, 209, 21928, 2294, 10507, 3623)\
                    order by count desc limit 10", conn)
```

I want to take the variable of the list add it to my query

This causes errors

```
Temp = pd.read_sql("select count(*) as count\
                    from "+db+"\
                    where ids in "+temp_id+"\
                    order by count desc limit 10", conn)


TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

I don't understand what I need to change here

---

**Answer**

Ended up taking the advise of the comments below and modified my loop which generates the temp_ids:

```
temp_id = []
for id in df['ID']:
    if id and id not in temp_id:
        temp_id.append(str(ID))        

        #Convert to list format
temp_id = ", ".join(temp_id)
```

2 things made this work :

```
str(ID) & temp_id = ", ".join(temp_id)
```

Comment: You could also use something like this: `"("+str(temp_id).strip('[]')+")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the variables as a comma separated string instead of an array.

So declare temp_id as string.

```
temp_id = "7922, 7018, 5650, 209, 21928, 2294, 10507, 3623"

Temp = pd.read_sql("select count(*) as count\
                    from "+db+"\
                    where ids in ("+temp_id+")\
                    order by count desc limit 10", conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need  a string so you should implode your array

```
temp_id = [7922, 7018, 5650, 209, 21928, 2294, 10507, 3623]


my_string = ",".join(temp_id )

Temp = pd.read_sql("select count(*) as count\
                    from "+db+"\
                    where ids in ("+my_string+")\
                    order by count desc limit 10", conn)
```